# 8 GB RAM support issue

Tags: memory, motherboard

My motherboard supports 8 GB of RAM. However, when I have the 8 GB in, the computer screen will not come on at all. It only functions with 4GB of RAM. (I have two sticks of 4 GB)

http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/G41M-S3/

CPU: Core 2 Quad Q8300
GPU: Nvidia 480 GTX
(Not sure what else I need to provide)

Comment: Perhaps one of the RAM is defunct, or one of the slots.

Comment: Can you test it with one piece of RAM. Then alternate them so you know both DIMMs are working.

Comment: In support to the above suggestion try to check all combinations `1 x slot - 1 x memory stick`. If both sticks are fine, but 1 slot is bad - the cause is MB. Once I saw buggy MB that simply could not allowed to plug 2 memory sticks.

Comment: @Hennes Both sticks of RAM work perfectly fine. Slot 1 works. When I plugged into slot 2 by itself, nothing happened.

Comment: if you are lucky one of the slots is merely blocked or has something in them short circuiting lines. If not then something is broken and you are stuck with using one DIMM. :(

Comment: Well that sucks ): I haven't taken out the board to check it yet. I'm hoping I don't have to return it to trade it out.

Comment: @Huydeebird - You have two identical sticks of memory correct?